# Icon gloss with iOS 6 & Xcode 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am really stuck on how to remove the gloss from my icon when using iOS6 and XCode 5.

I have read through these questions:

[Removing gloss effect from an icon in iOS 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740387/removing-gloss-effect-from-an-icon-in-ios-4-3)

[icon already includes gloss effects not working ios 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272502/icon-already-includes-gloss-effects-not-working-ios-5)

[How to disable highlighting of the app icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003177/how-to-disable-highlighting-of-the-app-icon)

And now my plist looks like this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.burton.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However, the gloss effect is still being applied when I preview the app on my phone. Any help would be much-appreciated.

Comment: The forums are up, that's the error URL you're checking. I'd recommend deleting your app, and doing a clean build.

Comment: You can't be that stuck, because you cannot use Xcode 5 to submit apps yet anyway.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Actually they have moved the setting. Under your project settings, under the general tab,and under the app icons section, select the "Use Asset Catalog". Now under the project files (far left panel) navigate to the Images.xcassets file. Now make sure the app icon and launch images are added. The important thing is to make sure that the tick box of "Ios Icon is pre-rendered" is enabled.You can find this option on the attributes panel (far right panel) when viewing the Images.xcassets file.   And thats it, you can delete the old images and do a clean , then build and run and you done. This worked for me...   [image]

Comment: could you provide an image pointing where is it? My attributes panel doesn't seem to show it. I'm using Assets Catalog, I have set all my app icons and I can't find that tick box here. Im using Xcode5-DP3. Tks.

Comment: Thanks! I've just upgrade to XCode GM and now the tick box appears.

Comment: I've ticked the box, clean, deleted derived data and the gloss still shows on iOS 6.

I had to reset the simulator for the change to take effect, presumably the users will have to delete the app and reinstall :(

Comment: Make sure you're in the 'Attributes Panel', not the 'File Inspector' - it's the button at the top of the far right panel.

Comment: OMG, thank you! This was driving me crazy!!!! Why on earth would they not move over the damn UIPrerenderedIcon flag when you create the image assets?! Grrrr. This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

After much poking around, it turns out this a bug with XCode 5 and the Media.xcassets folder that it uses to create the icon. I have submitted a bug report to Apple.

Answer (score 1):

After you set the "iOS icon is pre-rendered", you have to delete the app from the device and build-run again (in iOS 6.1).